# BottomSheetDialogFragment expands beyond status bar when soft keyboard opened

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I had a frame layout with RecyclerView with top garvity and  EditText with bottom gravity.
When I open soft key board the layout goes beyond status bar. 
I want the keybard to push only EditText  not whole layout.
Here is my setupDialog method:

```
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

    dialog.setContentView(bottomSheetBinding.getRoot());

    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);


    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);

            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
                    .setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried adjustPan and adjustResize but not working .

Comment: keep android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in respective xml file.

Comment: I tried it but still goes beyond status bar.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line instead:
`dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Comment: It's still goes beyond status bar